# Bug when attempting to restart program in C

Tags: c

As part of my program, I need it to run infinitely until the user enters the quit command.

I have tried re-initialising the variables, as so:

```
memset(word, 0, sizeof(word));
start = 0;
end = 0;
rows = 0;
```

etc.

The program takes in user input using fgets and places them into different variables using sscanf.
The output of this function is a table.

When I first run the program, it runs fine and the table is printed. The second time I run the exact same command, there is no table. However, on the third time with the same command the table shows up again.

I don't quite understand why this is happening. Here is the output:

```
Please input request (h-help, q-quit): scr 0 2.3 3

Degrees   Radians       Sin       Cos

0.000     0.000     0.000     1.000
32.945     0.575     0.544     0.839
65.890     1.150     0.913     0.408
98.835     1.725     0.988    -0.154
131.780     2.300     0.746    -0.666

Please input request (h-help, q-quit): scr 0 2.3 3

Please input request (h-help, q-quit): scr 0 2.3 3

Degrees   Radians       Sin       Cos

0.000     0.000     0.000     1.000
32.945     0.575     0.544     0.839
65.890     1.150     0.913     0.408
98.835     1.725     0.988    -0.154
131.780     2.300     0.746    -0.666

Please input request (h-help, q-quit): q
```

What is the likely cause of this issue and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Apologies that the table didn't print properly in the post

Comment: Where is the loop?

Comment: It is a very large code, I can't identify the issue so I don't know what parts to include in the post

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: That `memset` looks wrong to me. If `world` is not a pointer, it should be `memset(&world,0,sizeof(world))`. If `world` is a pointer, `sizeof(world)` is not the size of the whole thing you want to zero out

Comment: Please study the concept of [mcve].

Comment: Use debugger and single steeping to see the code flow, If there is no debugger, then use ```printf``` in your code to trace the flow. Such as ```printf("%s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__);```